# Ngingx returns 404 on local .ttf font

Tags: nginx, mime-type

I have a local .ttf font which I need to use. I have tried to edit mime-types

```
application/x-font-truetype ttfl
```

also tried

```
application/x-font-ttf ttf;
```

And mysite.conf looks like this:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  mysite.com www.mysite.com;
  location / {
    root   /var/www/mysite.com/public_html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
  }
}
```

But I still get 404 for the font. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Either you have the path incorrect or permissions are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are specifying `root` inside the `location /` block, and nginx does uses the default `root` directory from upper level in the `location` block matching the static files.

You need to move the `root` directive to the `server` level.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Moved everything from `location` / to `server` But why is godaddy in their nginx tutorial suggesting `root` in the `location /` level?

Comment: We cannot know the starting point they have used when writing their guide, so it is impossible to tell.